# "The culture that/in which we inhabit..."

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns, transitivity

> The culture **that** we inhabit shapes how we think, feel, and act in the most pervasive ways.
>
> The culture **in which** we inhabit shapes how we think, feel, and act in the most pervasive ways.

Is either of them wrong in some way?

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct; the second uses 'inhabit' incorrectly. Inhabit is a transitive verb, that is to say, we inhabit a place; we do not inhabit **in** a place, so cannot say 'in which we inhabit'.

> inhabit verb [ T often passive ]
>   C2
>
> to live in a place:
>   These remote islands are inhabited only by birds.

[Inhabit (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inhabit)